# Is it possible for an C/C++ application to use both localhost IP and remote IP for UDP communications

Tags: c++, udp, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have an application (CN) that communicates with couples of devices, one (A) is running on the same machine running the application and another remote device (B)  (on a virtual machine). 
My socket for the loopback address '127.0.0.1' binds fine and I could see the traffic on wireshark going to and from A. But the application CN fails to bind 'fails to bind, error 10049' to other address.  The local IP and port for Application (CN) has the normal class C Ip address and multiple ports for different messages.

What I'd like to know, can an application have different IP addresses : the loopback for comms with A, and a normal IP for B ? if so, why does that error say ?

Comment: An address passed to `bind()` has to be an IP addresses corresponding to a network interface that is attached to the local machine.

Comment: You can, however, `connect()` a UDP socket to a remote IP/port, then you can use `send()`/`recv()` instead of `sendto()`/`recvfrom()`